# How to efficiently convert a big one-column CSV file of float(s) to a binary file using struct pack method

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, struct, pack

I have some big one-column CSVs containing float numbers. I want to convert them efficiently to binary files using the `pack` method of struct module, with format `"f"`.

What I've done is this:

```
with open(input_bin_filename, 'wb') as binary:
    for d in map(float, input_file):
        binary.write(pack("f", d))
```

Is this the fastest way or is there any one-liner using map/reduce family methods?

Comment: Numpy has efficient routines for that: ``a = loadtxt("myfile.txt")`` (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) can parse simple CSV files and ``a.tofile("myfile.bin")`` (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html) can write it as a binary dump to disk. The reason for its efficiency is that Numpy arrays typically operate on continuous blocks of memory.

Comment: The title is a bit ambiguous: do you want an efficient solution, or do you want a solution using `struct.pack`?  They may not be the same thing.

Comment: @Dietrich I will try this, but I'd prefer a solution not dependent to numpy.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Why is it ambiguous? Is struct.pack inefficient?

Comment: @Chris: `struct.pack` used repeatedly in a for loop will be significantly less efficient than NumPy, yes.  It's a strange title because you seem to be both asking how to do something *and* already answering yourself by specifying the method you want to use, and in this case the method you specify is probably not going to be the most efficient one.